# How do I create next and previous buttons to navigate a list?

Tags: c#, list, winforms, button

I am working on this project and I am stuck.  I have a form and on the form, I have a Next button and Previous button:

[image: Form with the buttons and other functionality]

In my `HouseList` class, I have this code and what I want to do is to create a method to get the next house and another method to get to the previous house.  I have been trying for so long.

```
public HouseList()
{
    housesList = new List<House>();
    housesList.Add(new House()
    {
        Address = "35 Twin Oaks",
        City = "Glendale",
        Zip = "MDN6L3",
        AskingPrice = "328,743.00",
        PictureFile = "",
        AveragePrice = "490,747.80",
        Total = "2,453,739.00"
    });


    housesList.Add(new House()
    {
        Address = "35 Helen Drive",
        City = "OakDale",
        Zip = "G6L5M4",
        AskingPrice = "455,899.00",
        PictureFile = "",
        AveragePrice = "490,747.80",
        Total = "2,453,739,00"
    });

    housesList.Add(new House()
    {
        Address = "4 RiverBank Rd",
        City = "Brampton",
        Zip = "L9H4L2",
        AskingPrice = "699,999.00",
        PictureFile = "",
        AveragePrice = "490,747.80",
        Total = "2,453,739,00"
    });
}

public List<string> NextHouse()
{
    List<string> house = new List<string>();
    foreach (House h in housesList)
    {
        int index = 0;
        string conv = Convert.ToString(index);
        if (conv == house[1])
        {
            conv = house[1];
        }  
    }
    return house;
}
```

Comment: [`LinkedList<T>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.linkedlist-1?view=netframework-4.7.2)

Comment: May be this helps: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24799820/get-previous-next-item-of-a-given-item-in-a-list

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using next and previous buttons to navgiate through a list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25950482/using-next-and-previous-buttons-to-navgiate-through-a-list)

Comment: Use a [BindingNavigator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/winforms/controls/bindingnavigator-control-overview-windows-forms)

Comment: Or set the List as the DataSource of a BindingSource and bind all controls to the BindingSource. After that, all is automatic.

Comment: I don't really know how to do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would need to have an index which tells you which index is current. The index would be compared to 0 for min index and houseList.Count-1 for max index. With that in mind, `NextHouse` and `PreviousHouse` should return `House` not `List<House>`.

```
public House NextHouse(){
    if(currentIndex + 1 != houseList.Count)
        currentIndex++;
    return houseList[currentIndex]
}

public House PreviousHouse(){
    if(currentIndex -1 >= 0)
        currentIndex--;
    return houseList[currentIndex];
}
```

So if you ask for next house when you are already on the last house in the list, it will just return the last house. If you ask for previous house when you are on the first in the list, it will return the first house.

You will have to initialize `currentIndex` as class member to do this.

Comment: I tried to pass it to the Form.cs and nothing happened.private void btnNext_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            hList.NextHouse();
        }

        private void btnPrevious_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            hList.PreviousHouse();
        }

Comment: @Mohamed you're getting `House` reference from those functions, you need to use this retrieved value to put it on display. `house = hList.NextHouse(); //display house on form;`

Comment: I still don't get it. but i don't know if this is what you mean? House house = new House(); house = hList.NextHouse();

Comment: @Mohamed the houses are initialized in the `HouseList, once you have them, you can retrieve them using `NextHouse` and `PreviousHouse` functions. Once you retrieve them, you need to use their information to display them on screen.

Answer (score 0):

this is for next item:

```
public List<House> housesList;
    int currentIndex = 0;

    public HouseList()
    {
        housesList = new List<House>();
        housesList.Add(new House()
        {
            Address = "35 Twin Oaks",
            City = "Glendale",
            Zip = "MDN6L3",
            AskingPrice = "328,743.00",
            PictureFile = "",
            AveragePrice = "490,747.80",
            Total = "2,453,739.00"
        });


        housesList.Add(new House()
        {
            Address = "35 Helen Drive",
            City = "OakDale",
            Zip = "G6L5M4",
            AskingPrice = "455,899.00",
            PictureFile = "",
            AveragePrice = "490,747.80",
            Total = "2,453,739,00"
        });

        housesList.Add(new House()
        {
            Address = "4 RiverBank Rd",
            City = "Brampton",
            Zip = "L9H4L2",
            AskingPrice = "699,999.00",
            PictureFile = "",
            AveragePrice = "490,747.80",
            Total = "2,453,739,00"
        });
    }

    public House NextHouse()
    {
        return housesList[(++currentIndex)%housesList.Count()];
    }
```

this will loop when arrive to the last item. if you want it to stop change the logic.